# Adding a custom field in products description page in OpenCart 3.x

Tags: html, css, twig, opencart, opencart-3

I want to customize the product description page of my site which is based on OpenCart by adding an additional field, but i'm unable to fined the file that describes the description page. I have checked the **catalog/view/theme/(mytemplate)/product/product.twig** file but that's not the file for my product description page.

Comment: Actually it is. And of course corresponding controller file. Just after you edit your files, do not forget refresh modifications and clear cache in admin dashboard. All data which you want retrieve in template, must be defined in corresponding controller file.

Comment: @K.B. i have cleared the cache in admin dashboard and browser. I only want to add a custom section in the page.

Comment: Custom section, that you want to edit from admin panel? Like a second description? Write more details please.

Comment: i want to add a sub title below of the product title. I have searched for the extension for the same but could not find anything.

Comment: ok. i see. will write down a detailed answer for you, you should edid 6 files and Database. But don't worry. I will describe everything.

Answer (score 4):

Adding new field in product description OpenCart 3.X (multilingual).

On the **Dashboard** of Admin at the right top corner click on Gear icon. In the popup window turn the **Cache** OFF (both) and Refresh. This is necessary so that the results of your editing can be seen.

**1.** First of all, you need to add a new field in your database. Using **phpMyAdmin**, open your DB, find table **oc_product_description** (oc_ - is my prefix, use yours).

When you open **oc_product_description**, open SQL tab and write (don't forget to change oc_ to your DB prefix):

```
ALTER TABLE `oc_product_description` ADD `subtitle` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL AFTER `name`;
```

This will add a new column *subtitle*.

**2. Edition admin model** *admin/model/catalog/product.php*

Find (≈12 line)

```
foreach ($data['product_description'] as $language_id => $value) {
  $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "', name = '" . $this->db->escape($value['name']) . "', description = '" . $this->db->escape($value['description']) . "', tag = '" . $this->db->escape($value['tag']) . "', meta_title = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_title']) . "', meta_description = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_description']) . "', meta_keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_keyword']) . "'");
}
```

Replace with

```
foreach ($data['product_description'] as $language_id => $value) {
  $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "', name = '" . $this->db->escape($value['name']) . "', subtitle = '" . $this->db->escape($value['subtitle']) . "', description = '" . $this->db->escape($value['description']) . "', tag = '" . $this->db->escape($value['tag']) . "', meta_title = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_title']) . "', meta_description = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_description']) . "', meta_keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_keyword']) . "'");
}
```

Find (≈146 line)

```
foreach ($data['product_description'] as $language_id => $value) {
  $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "', name = '" . $this->db->escape($value['name']) . "', description = '" . $this->db->escape($value['description']) . "', tag = '" . $this->db->escape($value['tag']) . "', meta_title = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_title']) . "', meta_description = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_description']) . "', meta_keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_keyword']) . "'");
}
```

Replace with

```
foreach ($data['product_description'] as $language_id => $value) {
  $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "', name = '" . $this->db->escape($value['name']) . "', subtitle = '" . $this->db->escape($value['subtitle']) . "', description = '" . $this->db->escape($value['description']) . "', tag = '" . $this->db->escape($value['tag']) . "', meta_title = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_title']) . "', meta_description = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_description']) . "', meta_keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_keyword']) . "'");
}
```

Find (≈432 line)

```
$product_description_data[$result['language_id']] = array(
  'name'             => $result['name'],
```

Add below

```
  'subtitle'         => $result['subtitle'],
```

**3. Edition admin model** *admin/controller/catalog/product.php*

Find (≈500 line)

```
if (isset($this->error['name'])) {
  $data['error_name'] = $this->error['name'];
} else {
  $data['error_name'] = array();
}
```

Add below

```
if (isset($this->error['subtitle'])) {
  $data['error_subtitle'] = $this->error['subtitle'];
} else {
  $data['error_subtitle'] = array();
}
```

Find

```
if ((utf8_strlen($value['name']) < 1) || (utf8_strlen($value['name']) > 255)) {
  $this->error['name'][$language_id] = $this->language->get('error_name');
}
```

Add below

```
if (utf8_strlen($value['subtitle']) > 255) {
  $this->error['subtitle'][$language_id] = $this->language->get('error_subtitle');
}
```

**4. Editing admin language** *admin/language/en-gb(or your admin language)/catalog/product.php*

Add at the end

```
$_['entry_subtitle']         = 'Product Subtitle';
$_['error_subtitle']         = 'Product Subtitle must less than 255 characters!';
```

**5. Edition admin view** *admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.twig*

Find (≈50 line)

```
<div class="form-group required">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-name{{ language.language_id }}">{{ entry_name }}</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" name="product_description[{{ language.language_id }}][name]" value="{{ product_description[language.language_id] ? product_description[language.language_id].name }}" placeholder="{{ entry_name }}" id="input-name{{ language.language_id }}" class="form-control"/>
    {% if error_name[language.language_id] %}
      <div class="text-danger">{{ error_name[language.language_id] }}</div>
    {% endif %} </div>
</div>
```

Add below

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-name{{ language.language_id }}">{{ entry_subtitle }}</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" name="product_description[{{ language.language_id }}][subtitle]" value="{{ product_description[language.language_id] ? product_description[language.language_id].subtitle }}" placeholder="{{ entry_subtitle }}" id="input-subtitle{{ language.language_id }}" class="form-control"/>
    {% if error_subtitle[language.language_id] %}
      <div class="text-danger">{{ error_subtitle[language.language_id] }}</div>
    {% endif %} </div>
</div>
```

Now we can see new field in Admin panel while edition or adding a product.

Finally, we are going to edit customer side.

**6. Edition customer model** *catalog/model/catalog/product.php*

Find (≈10 line)

```
if ($query->num_rows) {
  return array(
    'product_id'       => $query->row['product_id'],
    'name'             => $query->row['name'],
```

Add below

```
'subtitle'         => $query->row['subtitle'],
```

**7. Edition customer controller** *catalog/controller/product/product.php*

Find (≈228 line)

```
$data['heading_title'] = $product_info['name'];
```

Add below

```
$data['subtitle'] = $product_info['subtitle'];
```

**8. Editing customer view** *catalog/view/theme/default(or your theme)/template/product/product.twig*

Find

```
<h1>{{ heading_title }}</h1>
```

Add below

```
<h3>{{ subtitle }}</h3>
```

Congrats! We have done it! After all thous manipulations you have to clear **ocmod** cache. Go to Admin, *Extensions - Modifications*, right top corner button Refresh. Than go back to admin Dashboard, click on right top corner Gear icon. In the popup window turn the Cache ON (both) and Refresh it. More about cache OpenCart 3.X cache cleaning here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61524855/3187127

This is suitable for any OpenCart 3.X, but in in some older 3.X versions you will have to clear **twig** cache by cleaning storage in file system.

Answer (score 0):

When editing a .twig file in OpenCart 3.x you will often face an issue with Twig Cache. You would edit the file and not see any changes.

To avoid this,
1. go to your admin panel 
2. in the top right corner click on the gear icon.
3. turn off twig cache.

let me know if this helps?