# OpenCart 3: system cache cleaning, ocmod and twig. I made changes in controller but its not reflecting

Tags: php, twig, opencart, opencart-3

I want to change something related to product attributes in the product details page: /index.php?route=product/product&product_id=100

So I changed
\catalog\controller\product\product.php file and saved it.

but it's not reflecting my changes even I removed the cache and refreshed the page but it's not working.
Even I removed the whole code in the PHP file. But it's not reflecting my changes

Comment: Which OC version? Anyway you should also refresh modifications of the extensions in admin. You didi it?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using OpenCart 3 - it might be **ocmod** cache or **twig** cache.

To clear twig cache in your admin dashboard click on the gear button on top right corner, and then clear the Theme cache.
[image]

To clear **ocmod** cache in admin panel go to *Extensions - Modifications* and click reload button in top right corner. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are here and your template is not updating, then the cache reset did not work for you. Indeed, this CMS has a problem with this. The only way in the **"Dashboard"** is to disable the cache in the templates, at the bottom, under the charts.

Then in the left side menu, open the **"Design"** tab,
In the dropdown list, find **"Theme Editor"**

[image: Disable cache]

Disable cache

[image]

Choose your store theme

**And click on the template to edit**

[image]

Very important! Make changes to the twig file.

Click the **"Save"** button!

Next, go to the site - *"Ctrl+Shift+R"*

*Your template has changed! :)*