# Basel Theme Carousel module full screen width on OpenCart 3

Tags: css, twig, opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

I am using Basel Theme on my OpenCart 3.0.3.2 store. I added Basel Carousel on my page but its showing margin on left and right side of the Carousel. Please help me with making it to full-screen and also I want to remove margin (space) between banners.[image]

I can provide you codes if you want. There is a twig, tpl and php file for this.

Answer (score 1):

Each module in your theme wraps in `.container`, and this wrappers you can find in

/catalog/view/theme/basel/template/common/header.twig

```
<div class="container">
{{ position_top }}
</div>
```

/catalog/view/theme/basel/template/common/footer.twig

```
<div class="container">
{{ position_bottom }}
</div>
```

Depends on which layout position your Carousel is. Just remove `container` from class. But in this case all modules in this position will be 100% width, know that.

---

Or you can do it with only CSS. Find and add at the end of a document

/catalog/view/theme/basel/stylesheet/stylesheet.css

```
.widget.carousel-widget.contrast-bg {
  position: unset;
  min-height: 130px; /* you can change it according to your images height */
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.widget.carousel-widget .slick-slider {
  position: absolute;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px 0; /* you can change it any way you like */
}

.grid-holder .item.slick-slide {
    padding: 0 5px 20px 5px; /* 5px is for left and right padding between images, you can set in 0 if you like */
}
```

---

**UPDATED**

All modules in this template are covered in `<div class="content">...</div>`, so we can release them by adding  `</div>..<div class="content">` around the module content. And this will be like

```
<div class="content"></div>
our module content
<div class="content"></div>
```

Go to *catalog/view/theme/basel/template/extension/module/basel_carousel.twig*

On the beginning of the document you will find

```
<div class="widget ...
```

Change it to

```
</div>
<style>
.full-width {
  padding-left: 40px !important; padding-right: 40px !important;
}
.grid-holder .item.slick-slide {
    padding: 0 0px 20px 0px; 
}
.grid-holder .slick-list {
    padding-right: 3px;
}
</style>
<div class="full-width widget ...
```

On the end of the document add

```
<div class="container">
```

And you can do the same in *catalog/view/theme/basel/template/extension/module/basel_product.twig*

Comment: /home//public_html/whitedotsports/system/library/template/Twig/Environment.php(312): Twig_Loader_Filesystem->getCacheKey('basel/template/...') #2 /home/darzixtq/public_html/whitedotsports/system/library/template/Twig/Environment.php(378): Twig_Environment->getTemplateClass('basel/template/...', NULL) #3 /home/darzixtq/public_html/whitedotsports/system/library/template/Twig/Template.php(286): Twig_Environment->loadTemplate('basel/template/...', NULL) #4 /home/public_html/wh in /home//public_html/whitedotsports/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_library_template_Twig_Loader_Filesystem.php on line 215

Comment: This is the page where I have added this module. https://www.whitedotsports.com/CRICKET

Comment: About cache cleaning for .twig files update here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61524855/3187127

Comment: I tried through CSS,
after clearing cache, it shows no change.Its same.

Comment: Try to add it in *Extensions - Basel Theme - Theme Settings - Custom CSS*

Comment: Hey, I can provide you with FTP details if you can fix it.

Comment: And admin panel. You will find my email in my profile.

Comment: You can send it. Then I will write down a solution here.

Comment: Hey, I have sent you the details. Please check.