# Proplem in my OpenCart 3.0.3.3. Directory not empty in developer.php on line 69

Tags: php, file, opencart, opencart-3

The error :

> rmdir(/home/amazonnc/ocartdata/storage/cache/so): Directory not empty
>   in /home/amazonnc/public_html/admin/controller/common/developer.php on
>   line 69

in the Error Log thans

> 2020-06-02 0:47:27 - PHP Warning: 
>   unlink(/home/amazonnc/ocartdata/storage/cache/cache.catalog.language.1591061429):
>   No such file or directory in
>   /home/amazonnc/public_html/system/library/cache/file.php on line 68

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if this file exists `system/library/cache/file.php`.
2. Check if all directories have permissions 644 and all files are 755.
3. Clean everything inside `system/storage/cache/`.
4. Clean the `.twig`. cache. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61524855/3187127

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by doing the following:

1. Delete all folders in **storage_folder**/cache except index.html.
2. Delete everything in the modifications folder except index.html
3. Refreshed modifications