# How to make category description shown at bottom and not at the top in OpenCart3?

Tags: html, twig, opencart, opencart-3

I know that it has to do womething with category.twig which is in /catalog/view/theme/YOURTHEME/template/product/category.twig

I tried to do whatever instructions I found in forums. 
[I tried this](https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=210166) and [I tried that](https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=199895)
I tried to refresh Cache. 
I need more help. What I am doing wrong? Or maybe these instructions that  I tried are wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are doing everything right. Make sure that in */catalog/view/theme/YOURTHEME/template/product/category.twig* **YOURTHEME** is actually your current theme. From the tutorial for thumb and description take this code

```
{% if thumb or description %}
  <div class="row"> {% if thumb %}
    <div class="col-sm-2"><img src="{{ thumb }}" alt="{{ heading_title }}" title="{{ heading_title }}" class="img-thumbnail" /></div>
      {% endif %}
      {% if description %}
      <div class="col-sm-10">{{ description }}</div>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  <hr>
{% endif %}
```

Or only for description take

```
{% if description %}
  <div class="col-sm-10">{{ description }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

And replace it anywhere in this template file (almost everywhere actually).

The most important is to clear **twig** cache. On howto do that i have described the process in the other article earlier, please read
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61524855/3187127

After that - click **Ctrl F5** if you are using Chrome or Firefox (or other combination in your browser which reloads page with cache cleaning) while you are on a category page.