# Class 'Twig_Extension_DTwigManager' not found in /storage/modification/system/library/template/twig.php on line 52

Tags: opencart-3

I am using opencart 3.0.2.0, I am new to Opencart and am stuck with this error.
I installed and uninstalled he module dadminmenucompiledoc3.0.3.1.v1.1.1.ocmod and after uninstalling site is giving 5XX error. On checking the logs I found this error message.
Didn't know that OpenCart is so unstable. I have already wasted my whole day finding the solution. There is no solution I could find. Please help. My production is down.

Comment: after you uninstalled extension, you should refresh modifications and clear cache in admin dashboard blue gear icon in the right upper corner.

Comment: How to clean the twig and ocmod cache you can read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61524855/3187127

Comment: Point is after I could do anything, website started giving 5XX. If you can tell me how to do it manually on cPanel I would do.