# How to change keywords in open cart?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I changed the Metatag Description & Key words in the admin side of OpenCart.
When I viewed the page source, the values of those fields are still the old values and hadn't changed.
How can I change these fields in the backend of OpenCart?

Comment: Try this please https://stackoverflow.com/a/61524855/3187127