# Opencart: Module Not Showing After installation

Tags: content-management-system, opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

I try to add Tawk.to module to my Opencart website, but after installing the module in extensions .. the module is not showing on any page of the website.

And after going to Layout I find it there but I do not know why it does not show on the website.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61524855/3187127

Comment: @focus.style Yes I tried it and still not working

Comment: Have you set permissions in your Admin System/User groups for administrator?

Comment: @K.B. Yes I set the permissions