# Twig how to display text only at the first page of pagination

Tags: php, twig, opencart, opencart-3

I've got OpenCart and theme using `twig`, how can I display my text only at the first page of the category and do not show it at the pagination pages.

My template looks like this

```html
{% if description %}
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:50px;">
        {{ description }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: test if querystring contains no page or page is one?

Comment: Thanks for you answer , could you explain it from the code side , how it looks like

Answer (score 3):

This check should not be executing in *.twig* template. This is a task for *controller*.

Go to **catalog/controller/product/category.php**

Find

```
$data['description'] = html_entity_decode($category_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Replaced it with

```
if ($page == 1) {
    $data['description'] = html_entity_decode($category_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
} else {
    $data['description'] = '';
}
```

Tested, works perfect. No template edition needed. Restore your *.twig* file to the original condition.

If you don't see any changes - clear caches according to this instruction https://stackoverflow.com/a/61524855/3187127

---

**UPDATED**

**Or**, if you want to check anything else in template

Go to **catalog/controller/product/category.php**

Find

```
if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
    $page = $this->request->get['page'];
} else {
    $page = 1;
}
```

Add below

```
if ($page == 1) {
    $data['firstpage'] = 1;
} else {
    $data['firstpage'] = '';
}
```

Now on your **catalog/view/theme/YOUR_THEME/template/product/category.twig** you can make check like this

```
{% if firstpage %}
    This is the first page.
{% endif %}
```

---

**UPDATED 2**
After previous manipulation your code should be like this

```
if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
    $page = $this->request->get['page'];
} else {
    $page = 1;
}

if ($page == 1) {
    $data['firstpage'] = 1;
} else {
    $data['firstpage'] = '';
}
```

Comment: deletet aproved all the data from the page , i mean main content  products plus discription text . )))))) So i dont think thats decision for me

Comment: Didn't understand. Can you show, what concert data do you wan't to show only on first page?

Comment: Updated the answer, look please.

Comment: Thanks for helping me  but  its still doesnt work . Says unexpected ElSE at category.php

Comment: I think you missed something. Updated the answer. There is a code as it should be. You only needed to add code to controller, not to replace it. Please, check very-very carefully.  every step i describe. I checked everything and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks man . I literally make all the steps as you describe and nothing going on. Im not able to test it one more time atm, but ill make it later in a few hours . So stay in contact.

Comment: Ok. I'm here all the time

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct you should be able to fetch the querysting parameter `page` inside `twig` with `opencart` like this:

```html
{{ app.request.query.get('page') }}
```

You could use this to test if your at the first page of your pagination with

```html
{% if app.request.query.get('page')|default(1) == 1 %}
     You are at the first page
{% endif %}
```

Comment: what if ive got  parametr at the end of the string .....page=2  ?))

Comment: Yeah  i mean ive got url like this https://somesite.com/topic?page=2 . Should your solution works ? Or need to change something ? Thanks

Comment: Well guess so yeah. The message will be shown if `?page` is not present or `page=1`. That is what you wanted right?

Comment: Ive tried it but seems it doesnt work  for me, and then i forgot to say that ive got parameter  in the end of the url string . But its only at the pagination pages. The first page looks like somesite.com/topic and other pagination pages are - somesite.com/topic?page=2 (3,4 and other).My case was like to show  text at the first page and do not show at other.

Comment: You've copied/pasted the `if` right and not the first line i've added?