# How to show Favicon (My website logo) on every page of my website

Tags: html, css, opencart, opencart-3

I have a website on opencart 3.0.3.2 and my home page shows my logo on chrome tab. I guess its called favicon. But when I open my product page, it doesn't appear. I have attached the images for clear information. Please look and help me to make favicon visible on all pages of my website.

[image: Chrome tab image with MISSING favicon]
[image: Chrome tab image with favicon]

Comment: sharing code is the best way to get answer on stackoverflow buddy!

Answer (score 3):

Simply add the following code to the `<head>` element in every HTML PAGE:

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.png">
```

Answer (score 3):

Save your `favicon` in the root folder of your website and add this to every page in `<head>` tag

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://shopinsports.com/favicon.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

Take your image `https://www.shopinsports.com/image/catalog/1ban/logo/feviLOGO.jpg`

Go to http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/

Using your image generate there `favicon.ico` file.

Put `favicon.ico` in the root folder of your website.

In your template *catalog/view/theme/YOUR_THEME/template/common/header.twig* add in `<head>` this

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

Go to admin panel and [clear your twig cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61524855/3187127).

Go to your product page and press `Ctrl` `F5` to reload page with cache cleaning (works in Chrome and Firefox)