# OpenCart site gets an error when logout -- ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, redirect, opencart, opencart-3

I'm using OpenCart to build my site now, but I got this `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` message when I logout. A few things are very weird:

1. after I saw this error page for 1 second, it's redirected to my homepage.
2. this only happens to Chrome, and I don't see this thing at all on Firefox or Safari.
3. The same error page asked me `Try clearing your cookies`, but after I clear my cookies for `All Time`, I can still see the same thing happening to Chrome.

So basically I'm not quite sure if this is something broken for my site, or it's an issue for Chrome browser.

Any idea how to debug and fix this?

Comment: I just tested it with Edge and got the same issue as Chrome

Comment: anyone can help?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have renamed you file **htaccess.txt** into **.htaccess**, so redirect should work correct.

Although, if your opencart website is not in the root folder of the domain and have path like `www.mysite.com/store` - open your **.htaccess** file, find

```
RewriteBase /
```

and rewrite it like

```
RewriteBase /store/
```

Answer (score 1):

For OpenCart 2 and 3

Open *catalog/controller/account/logout.php*

On line ~20 find

```
$this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/logout', '', true));
```

Replace with

```
$this->response->redirect($this->url->link('common/home', '', true));
```

Now it should work. In some cases you will need to [clear OCMOD cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61524855/3187127).