# How to solve this error opencart Notice: Undefined property: Proxy::getTotalCustomersByTelephone in

Tags: php, opencart-3

I use opencart Version 3.0.3.3

I try to use this to stop duplicate telephone number in the customer registration.

In `catalog/model/account/customer.php` add new function:
Code: Select all

```
public function getTotalCustomersByTelephone($telephone) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer WHERE LOWER(telephone) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($telephone)) . "'");

    return $query->row['total'];
}
```

In `catalog/controller/account/register.php` after phone entry check on line 237, before
Code: Select all

```
    // Customer Group
```

Add :
Code: Select all

```
    if ($this->model_account_customer->getTotalCustomersByTelephone($this->request->post['telephone'])) {
        $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_exists');
    }
```

But the result showing this when registering as a New Customer

> Notice: Undefined property: Proxy::getTotalCustomersByTelephone in /home/xxx/public_html/catalog/controller/account/register.php on line 245

Comment: `return $query->row['total'] ?? null;`

Comment: Make sure you cleaned cache of modifications https://stackoverflow.com/a/61524855/3187127

Answer (score 0):

I appreciated
thanks, you are Right, just I refresh cash and it is working fine.