# fatal error Uncaught Twig\Error\LoaderError: Template

Tags: php, twig, opencart, opencart-3

I am new to opencart and I have installed Opencart 3 and I am trying to install the following theme:

https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=39241&filter_category_id=1&filter_license=0

I have read several posts and watched many videos and followed the steps correctly. After following the steps i get a message "The theme is successfully installed". But when I go to the themes section in my dashboard in opencart 3 and select the newcrocus theme it gives me the following error on the homepage:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Twig\Error\LoaderError: Template
> "newcrocus/template/new_elements/product.twig" is not defined in
> "newcrocus/template/extension/module/featured.twig" at line 51. in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\azaan-leather\system\storage\vendor\twig\twig\src\Loader\ArrayLoader.php:70 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\azaan-leather\system\storage\vendor\twig\twig\src\Environment.php(299):
> Twig\Loader\ArrayLoader->getCacheKey('newcrocus/templ...') #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\azaan-leather\system\storage\vendor\twig\twig\src\Environment.php(381):
> Twig\Environment->getTemplateClass('newcrocus/templ...') #2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\azaan-leather\system\storage\vendor\twig\twig\src\Template.php(333):
> Twig\Environment->loadTemplate('newcrocus/templ...', NULL) #3
> C:\xampp\htdocs\azaan-leather\system\storage\cache\template\8e\8e5c9e03d41b9c67dbbfdfd20808223d84672524fec4b240d8d454a0e60d71ab.php(281):
> Twig\Template->loadTemplate('newcrocus/templ...',
> 'newcrocus/templ...', 51) #4
> C:\xampp\htdocs\azaan-leather\system\storage\vendor\twig\twig\src\Template.php(4
> in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\azaan-leather\system\storage\vendor\twig\twig\src\Loader\ArrayLoader.php
> on line 70.

Please help me with the mentioned issue. I don't know if the problem is in the template files or in the vendor folder.

Comment: Please verify that following file exists `newcrocus/template/new_elements/product.twig`, otherwise reinstall the theme or try to contact the theme creator

Comment: have you refreshed modifications and clear the cache in admin dashboard?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61524855/3187127

Comment: Yes the following file exists: newcrocus/template/new_elements/product.twig. But, I didn't see any changes in the modifications section in admin dashboard. I have not cleared the cache in admin dashboard. I will now try this and hopefully it will solve the issue.