# Autofill Email field with session value - Opencart 3.0.3.3

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

I have main website, where user logins... that time I am creating `$_SESSION['useremail']`.

My opencart V3.0.3.3 is in folder "Shopping".

I want to autofill email field in opencart (in shopping folder) login page with session value created by `$_SESSION['useremail']`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make changes in each controller, where you'd like to insert email from session.

For Login page open **/catalog/controller/account/login.php**

find

```
if (isset($this->request->post['email'])) {
  $data['email'] = $this->request->post['email'];
} else {
  $data['email'] = '';
}
```

Replace with

```
if (isset($this->request->post['email'])) {
  $data['email'] = $this->request->post['email'];
} elseif (isset($_SESSION['useremail'])  {
  $data['email'] = $_SESSION['useremail'];
} else {
  $data['email'] = '';
}
```

Now you will get your email from `$_SESSION['useremail']` on login page.

If you wish to add those email anywhere else on your OpenCart website - you will have to rewrite `$data['email']` in related controllers the same way as above.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I tried it But it is not working... Should I need to edit login.twig file too ?.

Comment: First - clear OCMOD cache https://stackoverflow.com/a/61524855/3187127 , just to make sure. Second . What will appear if you write `var_dump($_SESSION['useremail']);` in controller?

Comment: I checked... var_dump showing NULL in shop folder... but in other tab, on website it is showing email id logged in with

Comment: mywebsite.com >> login >> member redirected to member-area folder. mywebsite.com/member-area and opencart url is mywebsite.com/shopping NOW, on mywebsite.com and mywebsite.com/member-area, var_dump showing email id logged in with but NULL in mywebsite.com/shopping

Comment: I think, shall I need to php.ini in shopping folder (i.e. opencart folder) ?

Comment: Looks like OpenCart clearing SESSION before using. I can suggest you to use local-storage via JS. If you want - i will write down a solution.